# AVR atmega128 Serial comminucation

Tags: c, serial-port, avr, hyperterminal

I have a problem in connecting ATmega128 serial port to computer via USB-Serial converter. The USB-Serial converter is verified as I have connected computer to CDMA modem using it. However when I try to connect it with atmega128 I can't figure out the problem. I have connected it to serial LCD (CLCD) and it works fine.Even in simulation with virtual terminal there is no problem. I would like to know if I have missed anything related to serial port. I have already checked baud rate in hardware options and in virtual terminal.
Here is the code.

```
#include<avr/io.h>
#include<util/delay.h>

char str1[]="AT\r\n";

char str2[]="AT+CMGF=1\r\n";

char str3[]="AT+CMGS=\"01068685673\"\r\n";

char str4[]="hello\x1A\r\n";


int i;

void TX_CHAR(char ch)
{

    while(!(UCSR1A&0x20));
    UDR1=ch;

}

int main()
{

    UBRR1H=0; UBRR1L=103; UCSR1B=0x08;
    UCSR1C=0b00000110;

    while(1)
    {
        i=0; while(str1[i])TX_CHAR(str1[i++]);
        _delay_ms(200);
        i=0; while(str2[i])TX_CHAR(str2[i++]);
        _delay_ms(200);
        i=0; while(str3[i])TX_CHAR(str3[i++]);
        _delay_ms(200);
        i=0; while(str4[i])TX_CHAR(str4[i++]);
        _delay_ms(3000);
    }
}
```

Comment: you have tied the avr to the computer to verify the right bytes are coming out?

Comment: Does the USB/Serial converter have an RS-232 interface or a TTL interface on the serials side? Does your AVR have an RS-232 converter or are you connecting directly to the microcontroller?

Comment: RS232-USB converter is TTL interface

Comment: Connect your AVR to the modem, not the computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things to check:

- hardware - wiring
- value of M103C fuse (= compatibility mode)
- XTAL frequency and prescalers, as the formula for BAUD depends on it: BAUD = Fosc/16(UBRR+1)
- USART double speed flag (UCSRA)
- frame format
- UDREn flag set

You also may get better insight into your code if you use predefined symbolic values, e.g.

```
/* Enable receiver and transmitter */
UCSRB = (1<<RXEN)|(1<<TXEN);
```

see the examples in the [data sheet](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc2467.pdf) (pg 176ff)

On the frame format I understand you are set to async, 8-bit (`UCSR1B:2 = 0, UCSR1C:2,1 = 11`), parity disabled, 1 stop bit

In `void TX_CHAR(char ch)` I understand you are checking the status of bit 7 (RXC1) by using mask `0x20H`. On the other hand you dont have the RX enabled (RXEN1 meaning UCSR1B:4=0)

I wonder if you shouldn't better check bit 6 (TXC1). Again ... using the symbolic values would help to better understand the code.

Hope this helps ...